# Disable dynamically Button on react bootstrap table cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-table

I've emitting a button in a column of a react bootstrap table2, which should be dynamically enabled/disabled programmatically:

`{
dataField: 'dummy'
text: '',
formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
return ( <Button disabled={enableButton} onClick={() => handleDelete(row)}>Click!);
},
isDummyField: true
}`

enableButton is set via a hook to true/false. When I reload the page the button is accordingly enbaled/disabled, so when table is rendered again everything is fine (also when sort the content or filter etc).
Do I need to force the rendering again (and how)? Or do I miss something. From my understanding the update should be triggered by the hook, so manual force to render is a bit ugly.

Comment: is 'enableButton' a state (useState())?. Can you provide more code please, e.g. from your hook, what hook are you using to set 'enableButton' ?

Comment: The table does not re-render when the parent component's state changes. Unless: you force it to. One way to do this is to create the table `data` dynamically each time the state changes and the component re-renders, by calling map() on the original data and adding some row property based on the state. This way you can do `disabled={row.enableButton}`.

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested from Chris G, I renamed `dataField` to something meaningful and unique like "enableClickButton", remove `isDummyField`. Then, use the property `disabled={row.enableClickButton}` to enable/disable the button which works like a charm. Thanks!